# How can I resolve the issue of the excess blank space?

Tags: tikz-pgf, clip

I generated the following tikz codes through a software (with slight modifications), but I noticed a large blank space below the figure. Therefore, I wanted to use 'clip' (for example,   `\clip (-50,-50) rectangle (110,110);`) to trim it, but after several attempts, I still couldn't succeed. I'm not sure how to make it work, and please note that I also used the rotation command `turn`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{turn}{-135}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.07]
    \definecolor{marked}{rgb}{0.1,0,0.1}
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (29) 
    at 
    (42.567181,41.152087) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (28) 
    at 
    (27.572899,41.538022) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (27) 
    at 
    (34.919955,48.656375) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (26) 
    at 
    (43.524872,58.905088) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (25) 
    at 
    (50.014294,49.957119) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (24) 
    at 
    (50.586049,30.803317) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (23) 
    at 
    (38.607777,28.902230) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (22) 
    at 
    (14.923386,46.981133) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (21) 
    at 
    (23.883934,56.703831) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (20) 
    at 
    (33.919382,62.335620) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (19) 
    at 
    (49.428245,69.168096) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (18) 
    at 
    (57.432819,58.805032) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (17) 
    at 
    (56.518011,41.037736) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (16) 
    at 
    (57.132647,22.355633) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (15) 
    at 
    (45.452831,12.880504) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (14) 
    at 
    (0.000000,50.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (13) 
    at 
    (27.787308,71.898228) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (12) 
    at 
    (42.924529,75.687249) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (11) 
    at 
    (61.406518,71.054888) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (10) 
    at 
    (65.122928,51.400801) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (9) at 
    (66.137793,37.750144) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (8) at 
    (72.269869,28.201830) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (7) at 
    (50.000000,0.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (6) at 
    (50.000000,99.999999) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (5) at 
    (57.647227,84.048028) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (4) at 
    (72.427100,58.533448) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (3) at 
    (76.173242,45.410520) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (2) at 
    (99.999999,50.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (1) at 
    (84.005146,58.190395) {};
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (27);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (25);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (24);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (21);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (27);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (22);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (26);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (19);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (25);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (17);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (18);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (16);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (17);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (23) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (14);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (21);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (13);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (20) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (11);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (18);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (10);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (11);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to (10);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (8);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (15) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (6);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (13);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to (6);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (12) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to (4);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to (4);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (9) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (7) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (6) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (6) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (5) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (4) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (4) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (3) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (2) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (3) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (2) to (1);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (5) to (13); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (6) to (12);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (1) to (6); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (2) to (5);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (4) to (5); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (1) to (11);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (5) to (19);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (11) to (12);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (26);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (19) to (20);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (21);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (13) to (20);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (13) to (22);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (14) to (21);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (21) to (27);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (20) to (28);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (23);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (28) to (29);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (28) to (15);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (22) to (23);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (22) to (7);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (15) to (14);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (25);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (26) to (29);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (26) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (19) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (10) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (4) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (10) to (11);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (9) to (4);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (10);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (29);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (24) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (15);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (23) to (16);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (9);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (16) to (17);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (8) to (9);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (16);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (16) to (7);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (8) to (15);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (1) to (8);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (2);
        \draw[blue] (7) .. controls (-30,50) .. 
        (6);
    \draw[blue] (0.000000,50.000000) .. controls (50,-30) .. 
            (99.999999,50.000000);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}
\caption{$G$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've got also excess space just because of the curves. Load the [`bbox` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox) and use `bezier bounding box` with them. This saves you width and, more importantly, height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `turn` environment. Look at the

[image: fboxed original]

obtained by adding `\fbox` around the `turn` environment.

Skipping the `turn` environment and performing the rotation in the `tikzpicture` seems to work better. I just commented out the `turn` lines and changed the `\begin{tikzpicture}` line to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.07,rotate=-135]
```

to get

[image: rotating in tikzpicture]

Comment: Thanks. But what's odd at this point is that there's a significant amount of extra space around many vertices.

Comment: Then I suggest you ask a new question, linking to this one, showing those problems.

Comment: Ok, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695373/rotation-causing-gaps-around-vertices