# Rotation causing gaps around vertices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

The [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695366/how-can-i-resolve-the-issue-of-the-excess-blank-space/695368?noredirect=1#comment1726381_695368) resolved well by the user mickep, but I found `rotate` causes gaps around many nodes. The nodes and lines are not closely aligned.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.06,rotate=-135]
    \definecolor{marked}{rgb}{0.1,0,0.1}
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (29) 
    at 
    (42.567181,41.152087) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (28) 
    at 
    (27.572899,41.538022) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (27) 
    at 
    (34.919955,48.656375) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (26) 
    at 
    (43.524872,58.905088) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (25) 
    at 
    (50.014294,49.957119) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (24) 
    at 
    (50.586049,30.803317) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (23) 
    at 
    (38.607777,28.902230) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (22) 
    at 
    (14.923386,46.981133) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (21) 
    at 
    (23.883934,56.703831) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (20) 
    at 
    (33.919382,62.335620) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (19) 
    at 
    (49.428245,69.168096) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (18) 
    at 
    (57.432819,58.805032) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (17) 
    at 
    (56.518011,41.037736) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (16) 
    at 
    (57.132647,22.355633) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (15) 
    at 
    (45.452831,12.880504) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (14) 
    at 
    (0.000000,50.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (13) 
    at 
    (27.787308,71.898228) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (12) 
    at 
    (42.924529,75.687249) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (11) 
    at 
    (61.406518,71.054888) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (10) 
    at 
    (65.122928,51.400801) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (9) at 
    (66.137793,37.750144) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (8) at 
    (72.269869,28.201830) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (7) at 
    (50.000000,0.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (6) at 
    (50.000000,99.999999) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (5) at 
    (57.647227,84.048028) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (4) at 
    (72.427100,58.533448) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (3) at 
    (76.173242,45.410520) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (2) at 
    (99.999999,50.000000) {};
    \node [circle,draw,fill=marked,minimum size=0.18 cm,inner sep=1.5pt] (1) at 
    (84.005146,58.190395) {};
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (27);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (25);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (24);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (21);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (27);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (22);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (26);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (19);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (25);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (17);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (18);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (16);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (23);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (17);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (23) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (14);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (21);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (13);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (20);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (20) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (11);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (18);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (10);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (11);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to (10);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (8);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (15);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (15) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (6);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (13);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to (6);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to (12);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (12) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to (4);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to (4);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to (9);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (9) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (7);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (8) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (7) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (6) to (2);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (6) to (5);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (5) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (4) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (4) to (3);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (3) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (2) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (3) to (1);
    \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (2) to (1);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (5) to (13); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (6) to (12);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (1) to (6); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (2) to (5);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (4) to (5); \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (1) to (11);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (5) to (19);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (11) to (12);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (26);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (19) to (20);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (21);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (13) to (20);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (13) to (22);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (14) to (21);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (21) to (27);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (20) to (28);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (23);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (28) to (29);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (28) to (15);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (22) to (23);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (22) to (7);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (15) to (14);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (25);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (26) to (29);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (26) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (19) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (10) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (4) to (18);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (10) to (11);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (9) to (4);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (10);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (29);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (24) to (25);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (15);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (23) to (16);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (9);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (16) to (17);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (8) to (9);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (16);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (16) to (7);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (8) to (15);
     \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (1) to (8);  \draw [blue, line 
     width=0.25mm] (3) to (2);
        \draw[blue] (7) .. controls (-30,50) .. 
        (6);
    \draw[blue] (14) .. controls (50,-30) .. 
            (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$G$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

No such phenomenon existed before the rotation (we removed `rotate=-135`).

[image]

Comment: Good! This is a different problem, and I have no clue what is going on. I hope some tikzie will know and help. (+1)

Comment: Quick fix: Put all nodes in a `scope` environment and only provide the `rotate=-135` there and with the two curves: `\draw[blue] (7) .. controls ([rotate=-135]-30,50) .. (6); \draw[blue] (14) .. controls ([rotate=-135]50,-30) .. (2);`. Alternatively, rotate only the *xyz*  coordinate system: `x=(-135:1cm), y=(90-135:1cm)`. It also doesn't happen if you do `x=.6mm, y=.6mm, rotate=-135`. (I.e. scale the *xyz* cs and then rotate.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you, but I'm still not clear about your specific changes. Could you provide an answer, please? I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some conflict between scaling and rotating.

Since you don't use the [canvas coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.canvas) I suggest just scaling and rotating the [*xyz* coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz) by setting

```
x=(-135:.6mm), y=(90-135:.6mm)
```

---

I've also applied my [comment about the curves and their bounding boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695366/how-can-i-resolve-the-issue-of-the-excess-blank-space/695368?noredirect=1#comment1726377_695366) by loading the `bbox` library and using `bezier bounding box` on the last two paths.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-135:.6mm), y=(90-135:.6mm)]
\definecolor{marked}{rgb}{0.1,0,0.1}
\node foreach[count=\i] \p in {(84.005146,58.190395), (99.999999,50.000000),
        (76.173242,45.410520), (72.427100,58.533448), (57.647227,84.048028),
        (50.000000,99.999999), (50.000000, 0.000000), (72.269869,28.201830),
        (66.137793,37.750144), (65.122928,51.400801), (61.406518,71.054888),
        (42.924529,75.687249), (27.787308,71.898228), ( 0.000000,50.000000),
        (45.452831,12.880504), (57.132647,22.355633), (56.518011,41.037736),
        (57.432819,58.805032), (49.428245,69.168096), (33.919382,62.335620),
        (23.883934,56.703831), (14.923386,46.981133), (38.607777,28.902230),
        (50.586049,30.803317), (50.014294,49.957119), (43.524872,58.905088),
        (34.919955,48.656375), (27.572899,41.538022), (42.567181,41.152087)}[
  circle, draw, fill=marked, minimum size=.18cm, inner sep=1.5pt] (\i) at \p {};
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (23); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (27);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (25); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (29) to (24);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (21); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (27);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (23); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (28) to (22);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (20); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (27) to (26);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (19); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (25);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (26) to (20); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (17);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (25) to (18); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (16);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (23); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (24) to (17);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (23) to (15); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (14);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (21); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (22) to (15);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (13); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (21) to (20);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (20) to (12); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (11);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (18); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (19) to (12);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (10); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (18) to (11);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to  (9); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (17) to (10);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to  (8); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to (15);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (16) to  (9); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (15) to  (7);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to  (6); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to (13);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (14) to  (7); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to  (6);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (13) to (12); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (12) to  (5);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to  (4); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (11) to  (5);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to  (4); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm] (10) to  (9);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (9) to  (3); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (8) to  (2);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (8) to  (7); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (8) to  (3);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (7) to  (2); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (6) to  (2);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (6) to  (5); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (5) to  (1);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (4) to  (1); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (4) to  (3);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (3) to  (1); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (2) to  (1);
\draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (3) to  (1); \draw [black, line width=0.5mm]  (2) to  (1);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (5) to (13); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (6) to (12);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (1) to  (6); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (2) to  (5);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (4) to  (5); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (1) to (11);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (5) to (19); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (11) to (12);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (26); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (19) to (20);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (12) to (21); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (13) to (20);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (13) to (22); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (14) to (21);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (21) to (27); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (20) to (28);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (23); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (28) to (29);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (28) to (15); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (22) to (23);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (22) to  (7); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (15) to (14);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (27) to (25); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (26) to (29);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (26) to (18); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (19) to (25);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (18); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (10) to (25);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (4) to (18); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (10) to (11);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (9) to  (4); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (3) to (10);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (17) to (29); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (25);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to (15); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (23) to (16);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (24) to  (9); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (16) to (17);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (8) to  (9); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (3) to (16);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm] (16) to  (7); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (8) to (15);
\draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (1) to  (8); \draw [blue, line width=0.25mm]  (3) to  (2);
\draw [blue, bezier bounding box]  (7) .. controls (-30,  50) .. (6);
\draw [blue, bezier bounding box] (14) .. controls ( 50, -30) .. (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]